# Hi, Getting a No entry sign at the top of the desktop

Tags: python3

Hi im getting the following message,

The error message was: `ror in sitecustomize;set PYTHONVERBOSE for trackbase:EOFError: EOF read where not expected 4;1` This usually means the installed packaged have unmet dependencies

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try doing a sudo apt-get update and check whether the update is successfully happening. As far as I know your update would fail as guess there are certain entries in your souce.lst file which are not for your distro version.

Comment: Update worked fine.

Comment: Still getting No entry and same error within this sign

Comment: Just tried again and got (Sorry, Try again)for the update.